# Mobile Connect Auto Reply on STOP Keyword

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I am trying to get our Mobile Connect account to send a response message back to a user who replies to an SMS with the STOP keyword.

Currently when I reply STOP to a message I can see that my status is set to Unsubscribed but I don't receive a confirmation message.

I have setup a "Custom Response Text" on the STOP keyword.

[image: sms stop configuration]

Is there somewhere else in the account that I need to configure this?

I couldn't find anything in the official documentation.

Comment: Are you using a private or shared short code?

Comment: @RachidM, how could one check if the used code is either shared or private?

Comment: You can not check this inside SFMC. You should ask your account representative or ask the support. We had had this problem when using a shared short code. Check the STOP Keyword section here [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_short_codes.htm&type=5). Try to unsubscribe using another GSM provider and see if you receive the message or not.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your MobileConnect instance was not properly configured when you had your shortcode added.

When you filled out the Campaign Approval Form (CAF) with Salesforce to acquire a new shortcode or migrate an existing shortcode, you needed to provide Opt-Out keywords (standard opt-out keywords are `STOP`, `END`, `CANCEL`, `QUIT`, and `UNSUBSCRIBE`).
Included in the form is the Opt-Out Message Text to go along those keywords when subscribers text those opt-out keywords to your shortcode like you have above: "You have been unsubscribed from all future messages."

You need to contact SFMC support to get this fixed.